# Evaulation of $\int p(\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) d\mathbf{x}$

Tags: calculus, statistics

where

- $p(\mathbf{x})$ is the probability of multivariate Gaussian.
- $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is the multivariate Gaussian mean.
- $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this integral.

Comment: $E[(X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)]=p$ if $X$ is $p$-variate normal $N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48066/119261.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) \right] 
&= \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}\left ( (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) \right )] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[\text{tr} \left ( \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \right ) \right] \\
&= \text{tr} \left ( \mathbb{E} \left [ \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \right] \right ) \\
&= \text{tr} \left ( \Sigma^{-1} \mathbb{E} \left [ (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \right] \right ) \\
&= \text{tr} \left ( \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \right) \\
&= \text{tr}(I) \\
&= D
\end{align}

Note,

- Both $\mathbb{E}$ and $\text{tr}$ are linear operators, so the expectation of trace is equal to the trace of expectation.
- $D$ is the dimension of the multivariate Gaussian.